# Determining that decryption has occurred

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am developing a GUI based encryptor/decryptor based on AES-128 bit symmetric encryption.
My problem is that how to determine that **decryption has not occurred and show a dialog box "Decryption Failed"**. The code I have written would **always generate a file without a .enc extension regardless of the fact that it is still encrypted** !

Hoping to get a answer as always from Stack Overflow's top notch programmers :)

Do note that the decryption **process doesn't fail or throws exception** ! It's just the fact that it generates a file that's still not decrypted. That we have to stop and that's what I meant !

Code here: (Sorry for bad indentation !)

```
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
    import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.security.MessageDigest;

    public class FileEncryptor{

    private String algo;
    private String path;
    private String password;
    public FileEncryptor(String algo,String path, String password) {
        this.algo = algo; //setting algo
        this.path = path;//setting file path
        this.password = password;
    }

public void encrypt() throws Exception{
 SecureRandom padding = new SecureRandom();
 byte[] salt = new byte[16];
 padding.nextBytes(salt);
     //generating key
  byte k[] = password.getBytes();  
 MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
 k = sha.digest(k);
 k = Arrays.copyOf(k, 16);  
     SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k,algo);  
     //creating and initialising cipher and cipher streams
     Cipher encrypt =  Cipher.getInstance(algo);  
     encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
     //opening streams
     FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(path+".enc");
     try(FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(path)){
        try(CipherOutputStream cout=new CipherOutputStream(fos, encrypt)){
            copy(fis,cout);
        }
     }
 }

 public void decrypt() throws Exception{
 SecureRandom padding = new SecureRandom();
 byte[] salt = new byte[16];
 padding.nextBytes(salt);
     //generating same key
  byte k[] = password.getBytes();  
 MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
 k = sha.digest(k);
 k = Arrays.copyOf(k, 16); 
     SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k,algo);  
     //creating and initialising cipher and cipher streams
     Cipher decrypt =  Cipher.getInstance(algo);  
     decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
     //opening streams
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
     try(CipherInputStream cin=new CipherInputStream(fis, decrypt)){  
        try(FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf(".")))){
           copy(cin,fos);
       }
     }
  }

 private void copy(InputStream is,OutputStream os) throws Exception{
    byte buf[] = new byte[4096];  //4K buffer set
    int read = 0;
    while((read = is.read(buf)) != -1)  //reading
       os.write(buf,0,read);  //writing
 }

 public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception {
     System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
     new FileEncryptor("AES","sample.txt",new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine()).encrypt();
     new FileEncryptor("AES","sample.txt.enc",new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine()).decrypt();
  }
}
```

Comment: When something fails, an exceptio is thrown. To know why some code doesn't behave the way you think it should, the easiest way is to use a debugger and execute the code line by line, examining at each step if the variables have the values they should have. Learn to use your debugger. That said, you don't seem to use the same password to encrypt and decrypt. nextLine() returns the next line. Not the one you just read.

Comment: Assuming the decryption process itself didn't fail (ie throw an exception) the only way to "know" the data has been decrypted correctly  is to recognize it as valid data. If the decryption results in what appears to be random data then it likely wasn't a symmetric process. It isn't necessarily that it "failed".

Comment: You got it right user2864740 ....Can you elaborate please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the API calls, the decrypt methods should throw an exception if an error occurs.  In your exception handler, you can set a flag that will allow you to display an error message.  You can also delay the decrypted file creation till after successful decryption (or at least till after the first block has been successfully decrypted).  If decryption then fails further along the line, you can delete the (essentially temporary) decrypted output file and display the error message.

[edit]

I slightly misunderstood the original post, so some suggestions to check for failed decryption (note that these are higher level than AES, so it might be specific to your application only):

- Add a checksum to the plaintext data before encryption
- Append other metadata (file size, user, date, etc) to the plaintext, and check for these when decrypting
- Usually, a padding exception would occur on decryption - check for these (and any other giveaways)
- Use PKI (public key infrastructure) functionality such as signatures (this is outside the scope of this answer, and possibly outside the scope of the problem you're trying to solve)

Comment: Also, I don't know if you're specifically trying to detect a failed decryption (as an earlier commenter pointed out - normally you would recognise bad data when trying to use it).  If you need to do that, you could look at appending a checksum to the end of the plaintext file before encryption, and test for that after decryption.

Comment: That's a nice idea and that's what I meant...It doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Edited post with additional comments - sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: Relying on padding errors may expose the program to an interesting attack called the padding oracle attack which allows anyone to decrypt the ciphertext without knowing the key. MAC-then-encrypt also has certain weaknesses. You should either encrypt-then-MAC (using a proper MAC such as HMAC) or use an authenticated encryption mode like GCM.

Comment: Regarding...1.) Checksum - How to add a checksum to image or a video. I am a beginner so I don't know. 2.) Actually I have added padding in updated code...this was an old one. 3.) PKI...I don't know much about it.

Comment: @ntoskrnl, All very valid comments :)  I guess it depends on what exactly OP is trying to do.  If this is going to be production code, he should really look at tried and tested solutions (biggest mistake in crypto is trying to roll your own).  However, this looks like a small learning project?

Comment: @sidkamaria - What exactly is your goal with this program?  Depending on what you're trying to get out of it, I can point you to a LOT of useful crypto resources.  If that's not the primary focus, however, I can help with simpler suggestions.

Comment: @roelofs...It's just a Java learning project. Not an enterprise level code. I am beginner in cryptography...Just plunged into it before 4-5 days.

Comment: Ok, if crypto is not your main focus, then I'd just do a simple checksum (google will help you), append it to the file, and encrypt.  If crypto is a focus, I'd recommend doing some reading on public key cryptography (steep-ish learning curve, but essential if you're doing crypto), and especially signatures.  Appending a signature to the file will guarantee is authenticity, and give you an easy way to check if decryption occurred correctly.

Comment: Depending on the focus, you can also do what @ntoskrnl suggested, and look at the cipher modes for AES, and use one that will provide the authentication for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest appending a constant, rather than a checksum, to your data before encryption, and verifying it after encryption.

And the encryption algorithm should use chaining, that means avoid ECB (see here why: http://bobnalice.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/friends-don%E2%80%99t-let-friends-use-ecb-mode-encryption).

Using a constant with chaining, is nearly as good as a checksum and much simpler.